# Spark Java has trouble linking .js files

Tags: javascript, java, html, spark-java

I have a maven project that uses Spark Java to spin up a jetty server, and I'm able to link css files with the html, but unable to do so with javascript files.

The html head looks like this:

```
 <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Search for Classes</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/search.css">


<!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>  -->

      <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
```

As you can see there are two .js files, one of which is commented out, which I will elaborate on later.
The project has the following structure:

- src

  - main

    - java

      - project

        - Main.java
    - resources

      - public

        - css

          - search.css
        - js

          - jquery-ui.js
        - html

          - search.html
        - img
    - test
- target
- pom.xml
- project.iml

In Main.java I have `Spark.staticFileLocation("/public");` So that Spark knows where to look for static files.
Spark is able to properly link the .css files from my local directory, but for some reason however, it is not able to link the scripts for .js files. If I switch the comments, and instead link the script from `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js`, the javascript links properly. Let it be known that these two files contain the EXACT same code.

Does Spark-java have some special way of linking local .js files?

Comment: What is the url of your web page? Since you have added `../`, it seems you are not on the domain root, right?

Comment: "../" makes no difference. Search.html is the domain root at `localhost:4567\`

Comment: Have you tried to directly open `http://localhost:4567/js/jquery-ui.js`? If you make this work, then your html file should also work.

Comment: yes that works. but the java script still isn't working..

Comment: By doesn't work you mean the js return 404 as a resource? Or that the page javascript is not working as expected? If the standalone js works in a browser, the it should also work inside the html.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever resolve this?